# 'For loop' quits after 3 iterations

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers

I'm trying to write code to enter 'n' Number of sentences and store it in an `array`. My `for loop`  quits on  the 4th iteration ? Can anyone help me?

```
int main(){

cout<<"Enter the number of sentences: ";
int n;
cin>>n;
cin.ignore();
char *array[50];
int br;

for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    char* sentence = new char();
    cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" sentence: ";
    cin.getline(sentence,50);
    br=0;
    while(*sentence != '\0')
    {
        br++;
        sentence++;
    }
    sentence=sentence-br;
    for(int j=0; j<br; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = sentence[j];
    }

delete sentence;
}

for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
{   
    cout<<array[i]<<endl;   
}

delete[] array;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input, your output, and your expected output? Please post it EXACTLY as it appears in your terminal.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. The line `char* sentence = new char();` allocates only **one** `char` and you're trying to read (up to) 50 `chars` into it.

Comment: Also, `array` is an array of uninitialised pointers.  Assigning to `array[i][j]` therefore gives undefined behaviour, as does accessing `array[i]` in order to stream it to `cout`.   Also, `delete array` gives undefined behaviour, since `array` was not allocated with operator `new`.   In short, it is surprising your code does anything remotely sane.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* sentence = new char();
cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" sentence: ";
cin.getline(sentence,50);
```

This only allocates space for a single `char`, but you attempt to write up to 50 `char`s into that memory.  Accessing memory that you don't own causes your program's behavior to be undefined.

```
for(int j=0; j<br; j++)
{
    array[i][j] = sentence[j];
}
```

This attempts to copy the first `br` characters from `sentence` to `array[i]`, but `array` is full of uninitialized pointers.  Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer results in undefined behavior and then attempting to write to the memory it's "pointing" to is more undefined behavior.

```
delete[] array;
```

At the end of your program you attempt to release the memory allocated for `array`, but you did not allocate that memory via `new`.  Once again, undefined behavior.  `array` has automatic storage duration so its memory will be automatically released when it goes out of scope; you must not attempt to release it with `delete`.

---

Instead of a mix of static arrays and dynamic memory management, you should use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.  This will do all of the memory management for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Enter the number of sentences: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::vector<std::string> array(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter " << i + 1 << " sentence: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, array[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank on proposal, but I'm not allowed to use string or cstring library, I've tried to code from scratch and I think I got it.

```
int main(){

cout<<"Enter the number of sentences: ";
int n;
cin>>n;
cin.ignore();
char** array = new char*[n];


for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" sentence: ";
    array[i] = new char[50];
    cin.getline(array[i],50);

}

for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
{   
    cout<<array[i]<<endl;   
}

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    delete [] array[i];
}
delete [] array;

return 0;
}
```

Have I allocated and deallocated memory right?

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `std::string`, you should make your own `MyString` class that does the memory management for you. Please adhere to the "Rule of 3" when doing so.